How to overwrite a global variable's value by declaring it inside a listview
This is for a stopwatch functionality. The xCountUpDuration is the default time for the stopwatch and I have set it in 2 places, one is outside listview (Code 1) and the value is set to 0 and the other is inside listview (Code 3) and the value is set to 10 minutes. The problem is when I call the (Code 2) widget inside listview of (Code 3), the value is set to 0 instead of 10 minutes. How can I make it use the xCountUpDuration value set in Code 3.
Code 1
  Duration xCountUpDuration = Duration();

  Timer? xCountUpTime;

  void xCountUpActionStart() {

    xCountUpActionEnd();

    xCountUpTime = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => xCountUpActionAddTime());
  }

  void xCountUpActionEnd() {

    setState(() => xCountUpTime?.cancel());

  }

  void xCountUpActionAddTime() {

    final xAddSeconds = 1;

    setState(() {

      final seconds = xCountUpDuration.inSeconds + xAddSeconds;

      xCountUpDuration = Duration(seconds: seconds);

    });

  }

Code 2
  Widget xCountUpTimerWidget() {

    String xDigitConverter(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    final xHours = xDigitConverter(xCountUpDuration.inHours);

    final xMinutes = xDigitConverter(xCountUpDuration.inMinutes.remainder(60));

    final xSeconds = xDigitConverter(xCountUpDuration.inSeconds.remainder(60));

    return Text(

      '$xHours:$xMinutes:$xSeconds',

      style: TextStyle(

        fontSize: 60,

        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,

      ),

    );

  }

Code 3
return ListView.builder(

  itemBuilder: (context, index) {

    Duration xCountUpDuration = Duration(hours: 00, minutes: 10, seconds: 00);

    return Column(

      children: [

        xCountUpTimerWidget(),

      ]

    )

  }


Let your Widget know about the value of the variable:
return ListView.builder(

      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

      Duration xInnerCountUpDuration = Duration(hours: 00, minutes: 10, seconds: 00);

      return Column(

        children: [

          xCountUpTimerWidget(xInnerCountUpDuration ),

        ]
      )}

Code 2:
Widget xCountUpTimerWidget(Duration param) {

    String xDigitConverter(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    final xHours = xDigitConverter(param.inHours);

    final xMinutes = xDigitConverter(param.inMinutes.remainder(60));

    final xSeconds = xDigitConverter(param.inSeconds.remainder(60));

    return Text(

      '$xHours:$xMinutes:$xSeconds',

      style: TextStyle(

        fontSize: 60,

        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,

      ),

    );


Thanks for the help but both those solutions won't work, if I rename the variable then the stopwatch functionality won't work. I need to define the variable inside the list item because each list item needs to show a different time, if I remove it each list item will show the same time.

You should not work with a globally defined variable in your functions and in the widget. Carry out operations on parameters passed in the function so that you can change several instances of the variable and not just one. Start by passing a Duration as a parameter to your xCountUpTimerWidget inside of the ListView.builder.

If you can edit your answer with the solution you mentioned that would be great.

I did, let me know if it helps

Thanks. I tried it, it does display the individual time of each list items but unfortunately the count up function isn't working, the time remains static.

You have to change the functions aswell. Let them have a parameter and return the parameter value. You must change the individual variables individually, otherwise nothing will happen. Look up the term 'variable scope'.
